# Nesting while loop with for loop in bash

Tags: bash, loops

#### Description

Hello,

I'm trying to loop over certain commands and save their outputs into a file, and while looping through those commands, also check the file which we saved their outputs so we can compare them from the file while looping the commands at the same time. In the end, check if the looped commands' outputs match with the previously saved outputs in that file. *(Also check if the file doesn't contain the output and add it into the file so we can later use it to compare again)*

This is my main script which loops through the said commands which are located inside `/usr/local/bin/` so I can run them directly from the shell.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
wallets=`find /usr/local/bin/ -iname '*-cli'`

for i in $wallets; do
    current_blocks=`$I getblockcount`
    coin_name=${i:15:-4} # I use `:15:-4` here to cut the path and the last 4 characters. (For example it's `/usr/local/bin/bitcoin-cli` so I change it to `bitcoin` only
    echo $coin_name $current_blocks
    echo $coin_name $current_blocks >> blocks.log
done
```

And this echo gives us exactly this (assuming there are 2 items in the `$wallets`;

```
bitcoin 1457824
litecoin 759345
```

And this is the while loop I will -presumably- be using to read from the file;

```sh
while read line ; do
    set $line
    echo $1 $2
done < blocks.log
```

Which will also gives us this output when we run it;

```
bitcoin 1457824
litecoin 759345
```

So since I have these 2 code bits, now I want to merge them into a single script so I can both use the first code bit to loop through commands and also compare them with the `blocks.log` file. *(Again, also check if the file doesn't contain the output and add it into the file so we can later use it to compare again)*.

#### My first (and failed) approach;

```sh
for i in $wallets; do

    current_blocks=`$i getblockcount`
    coin_name=${i:15:-4}

    while read line; do
        set $line
        if [ "$1" == "$coin_name" ]; then
            echo "File contains the coin_name, compare the blocks now"
            if (( "$current_blocks" >= "$2" )); then
                echo "Current blocks are greater than the saved blocks"
                echo "Saving the new blocks count now"
                sed -i "s/$1/$1 $current_blocks/" blocks.log
            else
                echo "Current blocks are less than or equals to saved blocks"
            fi
        else
            echo "File does not contain the coin_name, adding it now"
            echo "$coin_name $current_blocks" >> blocks.log
        fi
    done < blocks.log

done
```

#### My second (another failed) attempt;

```sh
for i in $wallets; do

    current_blocks=`$i getblockcount`
    coin_name=${i:15:-4}

    read line < blocks.log
    set $line
    if [ "$1" == "$coin_name" ]; then
        echo "File contains the coin_name, compare the blocks now"
        if (( "$current_blocks" >= "$2" )); then
            echo "Current blocks are greater than the saved blocks"
            echo "Saving the new blocks count now"
            # sed -i "s/$1/$1 $current_blocks/" blocks.log
        else
            echo "Current blocks are less than or equals to saved blocks"
        fi
    else
        echo "File does not contain the coin_name, adding it now"
        echo "$coin_name $current_blocks" >> blocks.log
    fi

done
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `read` can split the line for you; no need to abuse the positional parameters with `set`. `while read name blocks; do ...; done < blocks.log`.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind, thanks for the tip.

Comment: That said, what is it about this code that doesn't work? What does it do, and what do you expect it to do instead?

Comment: Having the while both read from and write to `blocks.log` might be problematic

Comment: Basically, I'm just running this command `bitcoin-cli getblockcount` which gives you a number and I want to save this number so I can later (for example 1 hour later) run the command again and see if the number I've given has changed since the last time I run the command (1 hour ago, in this example). I'm able to do this one by one but I have more than a single command (`bitcoin-cli`, `litecoin-cli` etc.) so I want to do this in bulk by looping through the commands, saving their given numbers and comparing them between each runs. @chepner @Aaron

Comment: A better approach might be to simply have one tool append new data to the output file, and another present the changes in the file over time. You might want to rethink the details of your output format (maybe include a timestamp, maybe make each line a JSON blob with keys and values?)

Comment: Actually, I was going to include a timestamp but I'm just stuck right now and I can't go any further. I'm not sure how to solve this. @tripleee

Comment: [UsingFind](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/UsingFind) is worth review, btw, just wrt. the `wallets=$(find ...)` and `for i in $wallets`; likewise, [BashPitfalls #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).

Comment: I still don't understand which part of the problem you are stuck on, but abandoning this and just appending to a file would be very easy.

Comment: I guess this will be helpful to improve myself in bash, however I'm currently stuck with the overall idea of reading and writing from the file as well as comparing them. @CharlesDuffy

Comment: @tripleee I'm just stuck in general. :D I'm not even sure if my approach is correct or not so I just need a helping hand here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

In your second attempt you correctly recognized that the problem doesn't call for nested loops, still the `read line < blocks.log` is wrong because this reads only the first line repeatedly. Here's a corrected version with some remarks following:

```
line='' # no line read yet
for i in $wallets; do
    current_blocks=`$i getblockcount`
    coin_name=`basename $i -cli`    # I just prefer it more readable.
    if [ ! "$line" ]; then          # we need to read a line from log
        read line
        set -- $line
    fi
    if [ "$1" == "$coin_name" ]; then
        line='' # read new line next time
        echo "File contains the coin_name, compare the blocks now"
        if (( current_blocks > $2 )); then
            echo "Current blocks are greater than the saved blocks"
            echo "Saving the new blocks count now"
            sed -i "/$1/c$1 $current_blocks" blocks.log
        else
            echo "Current blocks are less than or equal to saved blocks"
        fi
    else
        # $line as well as $1 and $2 remain set, will be used in next loop cycle
        echo "File does not contain the coin_name, adding it now"
        if [ ! "$1" ]; then         # $1 is empty at EOF
            # create a new blocks.log to not disturb reading from original:
            cp blocks.log $$; mv $$ blocks.log
            echo "$coin_name $current_blocks" >>blocks.log
        else
            # insert before current line (address /$1/)
            sed -i "/$1/i$coin_name $current_blocks" blocks.log
        fi
    fi
done <blocks.log
```

Normally, we read one line from the log for each wallet in order, thus we have one `for i in $wallets` loop with one `read line` inside. But there's the case when since the last script run a new wallet accrued, which isn't in the file; here we have already read the next wallet line from the log file, so we save this line data for the next loop cycle and do not read a new line then.

Another important point is that we must not modify the `blocks.log` *input* file while the loop runs - this would add new to old data, mixing the sheep and the goats. Fortunately, `sed -i` creates a new `blocks.log` *output* file, while the old *input* file remains anonymously and undisturbed. Only when we `echo … >>blocks.log` we ourselves must ensure that a new `blocks.log` is created.

Note that this approach requires the wallets to be sorted; since your `-cli` files are all in the directory `/usr/local/bin/`, you can write `wallets=/usr/local/bin/*-cli` instead of the line with `find`.